# Can I use the same instance in two different entities in VHDL code?

Tags: vhdl

I want to use "inst_A" of an entity "A" used in the architecture of entity "B" in the architecture of another entity "C". I want it to be the same instance.
Like, I have used an instance called "s1" of an array of std_ulogic_vectors whose indexes are also std_ulogic_vectors. I am storing data in one entity and i want to read the data in another entity

Comment: You described a signal `s1` of type `std_ulogic_vector`. That's not an *instance*. What about connecting both design parts with signals and ports?

Comment: What have you done already? Please share some code giving an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

For synthesis, no. Each instance is unique; if you need to share data between two places, you must connect signals between these two places. It's not clear exactly why you have ended up wanting this; it sounds like you might want to re-think the structure of your design a bit, but without giving us any real information, I can only speculate.

In *simulation*, you can use aliases to access signals in the design hierarchy. Look up the `alias` keyword. I won't detail it here because I'm guessing that you are not after a simulation-only solution.